# Is it possible to know all potential parameters of url?

Tags: php, api, url

I have an API link with poor documentation. Let's say:

```
http://link.com/?<parameter>=###
```

Is it possible to know all the potential parameters of the url link without contacting the admin of the site?

Comment: Would you have the source of the PHP that you are passing these parameters to? If not then no, there is no "document this URL" command that works externally.

Comment: One really remote chance is to send an HTTP OPTIONS request. Very savvy API authors can code documentation into the OPTIONS response. I've done this for a few API enpoints to help make JavaScript unit tests, but this would be very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

With array_keys(), you can return keys of any array. We know $_GET is an array that have query string keys and values. With below command you can printing all keys that passed to this page:

```
print_r(array_keys($_GET));
```

instead of printing this array, you can use it as you want.